# Using Where-Object with an object in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, where-clause, pipeline

I can't seem to get my brain around something and I am hoping someone can help

I have an array of objects called `$SnapVMsAll` that looks like this:

```
VMName                    Name                                             SnapshotType CreationTime        ParentSnapshotName
------                    ----                                             ---------- ------------        ------------------
SHARED-server.host.com    SHARED-server.host.com - (02/10/2017 - 13:02:44) Standard     02/10/2017 13:05:58
```

I need to display all the records in this array of objects that have string "Veeam" in the name column, but I think I am having problems isolating a specific attribute of the object to compare.

My attempts have been as follows:

```
echo $SnapVMsAll | Where-Object (Foreach-Object -MemberName name) -Like "Veeam Replica"
```

This returned the error:

```
Where-Object : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Property'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
```

I have also tried

```
echo $SnapVMsAll | Where-Object $SnapVMsAll.name -Like "Veeam Replica"
```

But again I get the same error.

Comment: The `ForEach-Object` call makes no sense. Something like `where name -Like "Veeam Replica"` or `where {$_.Name -Like "Veeam Replica"}` shuold ne fine.

Comment: I suggest you to use the `Get-Help` cmdlet. Either `Get-Help Where-Object` or [`Get-Help about_pipelines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-6)

Comment: The Foreach-object is to try and navigate to the relevant attribute of the object, I accept its wrong which is why I am asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$SnapVMsAll` does not exist inside the pipeline, it is the object you pass *to* the pipeline. Within a pipeline, objects can be accessed using the automatic variable `$_`.

Also note that `-Like` is usually used with wildcards to match a string. If the name is `Veeam Replica` you should use `-eq`, if the name *contains* `Veeam Replica`, you should change to `-Like "*Veeam Replica*"`

So changing your code to the following should work:

```
$SnapVMsAll | Where-Object { $_.name -Like "*Veeam Replica*" }
```

Comment: That worked a treat thanks, I didn't actually realise that the $_ was for that purpose.